# LocalNotification Plugin doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, notifications

I'm learning PhoneGap and I tried to use the [Notification Local Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification%22), but does not work for me.

I'm trying to build my app, but it is returning error in XML AndroidManifest.xml. I followed all instructions in the README on GitHub.

I am using cordova-2.0.0 and API10.

Someone can help me?

Note: I changed LocalNotification.java:

```
//alarm = new AlarmHelper(this.ctx);
alarm = new AlarmHelper(ctx.getContext());
```

EDIT: My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.xpd.saleiro1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.phonegap.plugin.localnotification.AlarmReceiver" >
    </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.phonegap.plugin.localnotification.AlarmRestoreOnBoot" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Comment: what kind of exception does it throw you? could you please show your manifest file too. thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with a older version? When I tried i got successfully results with 1.6.1 version.